# Is normalisation possible with the existing database?

Tags: sql-server-2008, normalization

In our company, a product was developed in .NET as front end and SQL Server 2005 as backend.

Initially when they started the project they didn't follow the DB normalization techniques. Now they thought to go for DB normalization in which the database contains only one table that contains thousands of rows.

Is it possible to split this existing table and implement normalization?

Can any one tell me how to go step by step?

Thanks ,

Steve.

Comment: Possible - yes. Easy - no, certainly not. It'll be a hell of a job to get this single (presumably **huge** table) split up into parts. Might even be easier to just redo the whole project from scratch..... just don't let **them** do the new project again! Anyone **not** following (and using) **database normalization** for a database project should not ever be allowed near a keyboard again...

Answer (score 2):

Well, I’m a big fan of SSIS packages.
So, assuming you have your source table structure (the huge one) and you have already defined the destination tables, I would say just start building a package to migrate data. 
If you tell your table structure would be easier but I assume you have something like this:
Table Orders
Fields:
OrderId,
CustomerName
productName
And so one

That’s clear that you need a customer table and a product table so your first step would be to run a select distinct (CustomerName) from orders and insert that into your new customer table. Do the same for product and any other entity you may need.

To populate the new orders table you can get fields like the ordered or orderDate directly from the huge table and when it comes to the client (with is text on the old table and will be ID on the new table) you will need a lookup transformation task to transform the name to the ID.